# solve non-convex quadratic constrained quadratic programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

$\min_{\beta}\beta^{T} A \beta$

$s.t. \ \beta^{T} C \beta=1\ and\ \beta\geqslant 0$

Here $A,C\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times M}$, $\beta \in  \mathbb{R}^{M}$

I saw in one paper saying that it could be solved via its semidefinite programming relaxation by adding an auxiliary variable $B \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ like this:

$\min_{\beta ,B}trace(AB)$

$s.t.trace(CB)=1$,

$\beta \geqslant 0$,

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \beta^{T}\\\\ 
 \beta& B
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$

where $\succeq 0$ means left matrix is positive semidefinite.

I don't get how this is done, and besides, how to solve such a problem using any possible C/C++ software?

Thanks. $;)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $B = \beta \beta^T$,
the objective becomes 
$$ \beta^T A \beta = 
  \text{trace}( \beta^T A \beta ) = 
  \text{trace}( A \beta \beta^T ) = 
  \text{trace}( A B ). $$

Similarly, the constraint becomes $\text{trace}(CB) = 1$.

The problem is therefore equivalent to

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Find}\ &\beta, B \\
\text{to minimize}\  &\text{trace}(AB) \\
\text{such that}\  &\text{trace}(CB) = 1 \\
& \beta \geqslant 0 \\
& B = \beta \beta^T
\end{array}

The last constraint implies that 
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \beta^T \\ \beta & B \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}^T
\succcurlyeq 0$, hence the convex relaxation you mention.
(A relaxation is not an equivalent problem: you have dropped some of the constraints
to make the problem easier to solve.)

For a C/C++ implementation, you can check the [coin-or](http://www.coin-or.org/projects/) project.

Comment: Thank you! I already know why this relaxation holds. But now I am having trouble transforming it to standard form of SDP which doesn't have any inequality constraints in it.

Comment: That is easy: the inequality $\beta \geqslant 0$ 
can be written as $\text{diag}(\beta) \succcurlyeq 0$.

Comment: thanks, but I am gonna use some callable functions of CSDP or SDPA which needs a single variable matrix and no inequality constraints.
$;)$

Comment: The problem would then be: find $X \succcurlyeq 0$
to maximize $\text{trace}(AB)$ such that $\text{trace}(CB)=1$
and $X$ is of the form 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{diag}(\beta) & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & \beta^T \\
  0 & \beta & B
\end{pmatrix}. $$
The constraints (the trace, and the shape of the matrix) are linear but may be cumbersome 
to transform to the exact form expected by the software.